# Latest ckeditor (with jquery adapter) not showing images upload/browser?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have installed the latest ckeditor with jquery adapter, but I cannot use its image upload/browse server function. How do I add this feature? I am googling for hours and I can't find any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add your own file browser, you should follow the steps outlined at the docs:   http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29/Custom_File_Browser

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor does not have the filemanager in default installation, but you can install that you like. There many filemangers that can be integrated with CKEditor. [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) from developers of CKEditor is one of the best (presents in the CKEditor demos) but paid. [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/) can be good free alternative.